# Is it clear and natural to connect two sentences using the conjunction "while"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

[According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/while?q=While), "while" as a "conjunction" means

> compared with the fact that; but

as in this example

> Tom is very extroverted and confident **while** Katy's shy and quiet.

In the post [The US/British tag on Merriam-Webster](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/256576/117396), I wrote

> On the "Definition of in school" page of Merriam-Webster, the `US` tag is used. **While** the "Definition of at school" page uses the `British` tag.

Where I was trying to connect two sentences using the conjunction "while" and compare two uses. Did I use it correctly? Are there any other expressions more natural could be used here?

Comment: If you join the two sentences, the use is correct, otherwise it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example:

> Tom is very extroverted and confident **while** Katy's shy and quiet.

This example is clear and natural. However, if your intended meaning of "while" is equivalent to another conjunction like "but" or "yet", I think it is clearer to use the alternative conjunction, since "while" also has a temporal definition ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/while?q=While)):

> during the time that, or at the same time as

It is possible for someone to interpret the meaning of "while" temporally, although they would likely need more context:

> During the times Tom is very extroverted and confident, Katy is shy and quiet.

Second example:

> On the "Definition of in school" page of Merriam-Webster, the US tag is used. **While** the "Definition of at school" page uses the British tag.

Your second sentence is incomplete; it is a sentence fragment. It would be fixed if you change the period into a comma:

> On the "Definition of in school" page of Merriam-Webster, the US tag is **used, while** the "Definition of at school" page uses the British tag.

Answer (score 0):

"While" as a conjunction is used to join two clauses separated by a comma, not two sentences. So your example should instead be written:

> On the "Definition of in school" page of Merriam-Webster, the `US` tag
> is used, while the "Definition of at school" page uses the `British`
> tag.

Some more examples:

> One difference is that leopards have spots, while tigers have stripes.

> His persistence, while charming at first, quickly became annoying.

> While the cat's away, the mice will play.